# Publishing a paid Ionic App (self signed) to Google Playstore - Is adding license key necessary?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've an app built using Ionic framework, and it is ready for publishing.

I've self-signed it (using jarsigner) by following the steps under the section [publishing your app](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html) on Ionic's site.

Eg:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk`
```

Now, I'm on GooglePlay Developer Console, and it is asking me to get a license key for paid apps. When I click on it, I get a public key along with the below instruction.

*'Base64-encoded RSA public key to include in your binary. Please remove any spaces.'*

I've gone through the below link as well, but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html

Is this step necessary or is it same as the signing part using jarsigner provided on Ionic site?

If it's necessary, how can I include the public key in my Ionic App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not required,
Basically, this is a a system to allow for your app to check the Google Servers with the public key, and determine (based on the response) how your apps behavior should continue (or not).

If you are not concerned with applying licensing restrictions, then it is absolutely not required in your final apk.

You can read more here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html